# Using special characters in mysql table or column name

Tags: mysql

I have seen other questions related to using special characters in column name but I didn't get my point. I want to use column name like

```
 `first_name@abc|xyz|exy#`
```

Is it legal does it cause any security issue or any error while querying them?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 5.7 sets the encoding of the column names to utf-8 by default.

If you want to see the configuration in your system, execute the following command:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_results';
```

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-metadata.html